# error: forrtl: severe end-of-file during read of an unformatted file

Tags: io, fortran, intel, intel-fortran

I am having problems writing and reading large files when using Intel compilers.

To narrow it down I wrote a simple routine that writes a file 2 ways and then immediately reads it.

```
    program readvmold
implicit none
integer :: i,j

real(8),allocatable :: WMSH(:),RMSH(:,:)
integer :: NMSH,JCALC, ierr
integer :: NMSH2,JCALC2

NMSH = 39691212
JCALC = 1

allocate(WMSH(NMSH),RMSH(3,NMSH),STAT=i)
 if(i/=0)write(6,*)'error allocating wmsh'

! fill with test numbers
  do i=1,NMSH
   WMSH(i)=real(i)
   RMSH(1,i)=real(i)
   RMSH(2,i)=real(i+1)
   RMSH(3,i)=real(i+2)
  end do

! -------------------------------------------------------------------------
! test stream filetype
write(6,*)'writing VM2',NMSH,JCALC
open(103,file='VM2',FORM='UNFORMATTED',ACCESS='STREAM')
  rewind(103)
  WRITE(103) NMSH,JCALC
  WRITE(103)((RMSH(J,I),J=1,3),I=1,NMSH)
  WRITE(103)(WMSH(I),I=1,NMSH)
  close(103)

j=-1;i=-1

open(103,file='VM2',FORM='UNFORMATTED',STATUS='OLD',ACCESS='STREAM')
  rewind(103)
  READ(103,END=103) NMSH2,JCALC2
  write(6,*)'2: TOTAL NUMBER OF MESH POINTS: ',NMSH2,JCALC2
  READ(103,END=103)((RMSH(J,I),J=1,3),I=1,NMSH)
  READ(103,END=103)(WMSH(I),I=1,NMSH)
  CLOSE(103)

write(6,*)'done reading VM2'

! check wmsh
  ierr=0
  do i=1,NMSH
    if(RMSH(1,i)/=real(i))ierr=ierr+1
    if(RMSH(2,i)/=real(i+1))ierr=ierr+1
    if(RMSH(3,i)/=real(i+2))ierr=ierr+1
    if(WMSH(i)/=real(i)) ierr=ierr+1
  end do
 write(6,*)'Stream writing passed'
 if(ierr>0)write(6,*)'stream errors:',ierr
 go to 150
103 write(6,*)'END 103:j,i',j,i
150 continue
! -------------------------------------------------------------------------
! fill with test numbers
  do i=1,NMSH
   WMSH(i)=real(i)
   RMSH(1,i)=real(i)
   RMSH(2,i)=real(i+1)
   RMSH(3,i)=real(i+2)
  end do
! test rewriting VMOLD
write(6,*)'writing VM3',NMSH,JCALC
open(103,FILE='VM3',FORM='UNFORMATTED',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
  rewind(103)
  WRITE(103) NMSH,JCALC
  WRITE(103)((RMSH(J,I),J=1,3),I=1,NMSH)
  WRITE(103)(WMSH(I),I=1,NMSH)
  close(103)
write(6,*)'done writing VM3'

j=-1;i=-1

open(103,FILE='VM3',FORM='UNFORMATTED',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
  rewind(103)
  READ(103) NMSH2,JCALC2
  write(6,*)'3: TOTAL NUMBER OF MESH POINTS: ',NMSH2,JCALC2
   if(NMSH2/=NMSH)write(6,*)'NMSH2 not equal to NMSH',NMSH2,NMSH
  READ(103,END=200)((RMSH(J,I),J=1,3),I=1,NMSH)
  READ(103,END=300)(WMSH(I),I=1,NMSH)
  CLOSE(103)

 write(6,*)'done reading WMSH3'
! check wmsh
  ierr=0
  do i=1,NMSH
    if(RMSH(1,i)/=real(i))ierr=ierr+1
    if(RMSH(2,i)/=real(i+1))ierr=ierr+1
    if(RMSH(3,i)/=real(i+2))ierr=ierr+1
    if(WMSH(i)/=real(i)) ierr=ierr+1
  end do
 write(6,*)'VM3 read passed'
 if(ierr>0)write(6,*)'non-stream errors:',ierr
! end test
  go to 250

200 write(6,*)'END 200:j,i',j,i
  go to 250
300 write(6,*)'END 300:j,i',j,i

250 continue


deallocate(WMSH,RMSH)
end program readvmold
```

At some point during the first read it will either go to 200, or crash with error:

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 100, file /global/u2/c/cdiaz/NRLMOL_CURRENT/git/vmold/VM3
```

If I use `ACCESS='STREAM'` to write and read, I don't see this issue. I would prefer not to use stream, because it will make the code unable to read files generated by older versions, which we need for restarting calculations.
I only tried that because I saw it suggested in some other similar situations, but I don't really understand why it works over the other way.

I'm using ifort 17.0.1.132 in the intel/6.0.3 NERSC module by default, which fails. Intel/6.0.1 works only if I use -O0 optimization.

I've tested it on a different nersc computer that shows ifort Version 15.0.1.133 Build 20141023, and it works fine.

Comment: why dont you want to use stream access?

Comment: Where are your variables declared? How big are those arrays? Read [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same ifort compiler. The compiler is what's available on NERSC computers. http://www.nersc.gov/users/software/compilers/intel-fortran-c-and-c/

Comment: Your file cannot be compiled. Please make sure your code can be compiled and that  **you can reproduce the error** with that **exact** code. I am not able to get any error when running your code (after I corrected it).

Comment: Also be adviced that writing and reading  just `RMSH` instead of `((RMSH(J,I),J=1,3),I=1,NMSH)` can be a lot faster. Really a lot.

Comment: @vladimir thank you for the help, this is my first time asking a question here so I didn't know how much of the code to post. I've edited the routine which is now the exact copy of what I'm using. Thanks for the advice on the RMSH writing, too, I'll probably use that in newer sections of the code.

Comment: are you saying you get that end of file error with the version of the code that has `end=` on every read?   Try putting a system call (`Execute_command_line`) to check the file size after writing.

Comment: I would DEALLOCATE the arrays after the write. Then on the read... once you have the sizes... then re ALLOCATE, and read them in without the loop stiff that @VladimirF suggested. Change those WRITE(6,*) to WRITE(*,*) while you are at it.

Comment: I don't think deallocate would fix it. I don't know whre the problem is, maybe something specific to that supercimputer, but in modern Fortran you don't need deallocate too often.

Comment: I think you're right and it may be something specific to that computer. 
Is there anywhere you could suggest where I could read on the ways these print? All I know is there is some difference in markers of where lines start.